# Setting port exceptions for Windows Firewall via GPO. Is there a limit on the number of exceptions that can be set?

Tags: active-directory

We would like to utilize GPOs to manage our Windows Firewall rule set. We have servers that have different requirements (HL7 connections, other programs) and our doctrine is to only open ports that are going to be used.

We need to be able to audit and enforce these standards, so GPOs seem to make the most sense to me.

The problem I am running into is when I attempt to define multiple Windows Firewall Inbound Port Exceptions. (More than 10) After "Applying and Okaying" I will go to verify the firewall rule-set but I find that quite a few of them are missing. It seems like I am limited to 8-9 port exceptions per GPO.

I am unable to locate any documentation about this, but we can work around this by creating multiple GPOs.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Domain Function level: Windows Server 2008

Comment: Update: It looks like I can add as many port exceptions that I want initially, and all of them will show up. However, if I try to edit the list and add one more port exception. I end up with just 9 exceptions in total. I don't understand why this is happen. Very frustrating.

Comment: Made an error when creating the policy. I can create as many port exceptions as I like now.
I used the legacy rules/exceptions under administrative templates and not the Windows Firewall with Advanced security rules under 
Windows Settings\Security Settings\Windows Firewall with Advanced security.